# How to find the right selector for form modification using css?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Html:

```
<form class="awpcp-search-ads-form" method="get" 
action="https://adsler.co.uk/search- 
adsler/"name="myform">
<input type="hidden" name="awpcp-step" 
value="dosearch" />
<p class='awpcp-form-spacer'>
<label for="query">Search for Ads containing this word or 
phrase:</label>
<input type="text" id="query" class="awpcp-textfield 
inputbox" size="50" name="keywordphrase" value="" />
 </p><p class="awpcp-form-spacer">
 <label class="awpcp-category-dropdown-label" 
 for="awpcp-category-dropdown">Ad Category</label>
```

How do I find the right selector for css modification here?

tried `awpcp-search-ads-form`, didn't work.

If I try this in Codepen, it doesn't work

```
.awpcp-search-ads-form {border-radius: 20px; border- 
color: black;}
```

Comment: The selector is `.awpcp-search-ads-form`, with a dot. What does your CSS look like and what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am assuming you need css selector, so it will be `.awpcp-search-ads-form`

Comment: It's not. `awpcp-search-ads-form.` I tried in codepen. Didn't work. Want.awpcp-search-ads-form {border-radius: 20px;}

Comment: @Nac Doest it even have a background or a border ? If not, border-radius won't do anything...

Comment: @Amaury Hanser page ref https://adsler.co.uk/search-adsler/. It has a grey border, but even if I do`.awpcp-ads-search-form {border-radius: 20px; border-color: black;}` it still doesn't work....

Comment: Do you mean `awpcp-search-ads-form`or `awpcp-ads-search-form` ?
Because one exists, the other not... and you try to still the non-existent one.

Comment: It's a `class` name you are trying to select so you need a `.` before the name like `.awpcp-search-ads-form`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We ask that questions present a [mcve] for this very reason. If your existing css has a more specific rule that is turning off border-radius then answers as to how to correct the selector, while right, are not going to help you.

Comment: @jason. Hi. And thanks for that. But it didn't work in code pen so I'm just assuming the issue must be with with the css selector as there's no predefined css controlling it in codepen, or fiddle.

Comment: @miroslav I tried that. Didn't work

Comment: @Amaury good point, well noticed, my bad, but just a typo and still doesn't work. Try in Fiddle and you'll see.

Comment: @Nac close your form

Comment: @Fundhand please see updated question. It isn't the right selector in codepen or fiddle, so can't be for the site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried !important ? e.g:

```
.awpcp-search-ads-form {border-radius: 20px !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks but I can't see how important would work seeing as though the code itself doesn't work in codepen or fiddle.`Important`. as I'm sure you know, overrides predefined styles. In codepen or fiddle, there are no styles to override so must be an issue with the css selector?